# set current user in context using apollo server

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo

i have this middleware and need to get current user to set it in context of apollo server

```
 app.use(async (req, res, next)=>{
 const token = req.headers['authorization'];
 if(token !== "null"){
  try {
      const currentUser = await  jwt.verify(token, process.env.SECRET)
      req.currentUser = currentUser;
  } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
  }


 }
 next()

   })
```

and need to set current user in context

```
  const SERVER = new ApolloServer({
      schema,
      context:{
          currentUser //need to set this current user
         }
  })


   SERVER.applymiddleware({app})
```

Answer (score 3):

the context api in Apollo server offers handling request as follows

```
const initGraphQLserver = () => {
  const graphQLConfig = {
    context: ({ req, res }) => ({
      user: req.user,
    }),
    rootValue: {},
    schema,
  };

  const apolloServer = new ApolloServer(graphQLConfig);
  return apolloServer;
};
```

This will assume that you will have proper middleware that will parse the cookie or header. This is dependent on your authentication mechanism as you need to have set user for the request in some middleware before, if you would like to use JWT, you can use for example this middleware

```
const auth = (req, res, next) => {
  if (typeof req.headers.authorization !== 'string') {
    return next();
  }

  const header = req.headers.authorization;
  const token = header.replace('Bearer ', '');
  try {
    const jwtData = jwt.verify(token, JWT_SECRET);
    if (jwtData && jwtData.user) {
      req.user = jwtData.user;
    } else {
      console.log('Token was not authorized');
    }
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Invalid token');
  }
  return next();
};
```

This middleware will inject user if the jwt token is correct, then in your server file you will need to have the following order of middlewares

```
const app = express();

app.use(auth);

initGraphQLserver().applyMiddleware({ app });
```

Now you should have user in your schema context. I hope that it is clear, the code is not completed, but should be easy to finalize everything.

Comment: @mu_ali7963 does that work for you? If yes, need your help with the same scenario which I'm in now..

Comment: sorry for that long time not responde you could use  context: req => ({...req}) and verify your token and put userId on request like this req.userId = userId